# print path from any file

Tags: python, bash

I have a folder called project and inside it there are some other folder inside it called api, js, image, json etc.
each folder conatains some sorts of file. And each file conatins path like /admin, /api, /login, /see?url=$(url) something like these.

My question is.
How can extract those paths just by feeding the folder path. like.
`bash tool.sh FOLDER-NAME` 
And it should print the paths like this.
`/login`

`/admin`

`/api`

`/see?url=$(url)`

Comment: Recursively list all the files in the folder, and read and print their contents? What part is problematic for you?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: So you want to know all subdirectories in a directory tree rooted under _FOLDER-NAME_. Why is this question tagged bash **and** Python? This can be easily done in both languages, but - not surprisingly - in different ways. Make up your mind which language you want to use, and post your own attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: I dont want to list all the files inside all those directories or subdirectories.
i just want the tool to print those url path from all those files.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for
`tree -dif`.

`tree` recursively lists all files of a directory,

`-d` shows directories only

`-i` prints the tree without indention lines

`-f` prints the full path

However, if you actually don't want to list the directories recursively then just go for `ls -d */`, which will list directory contents (`-d */` for dirs only)